How to nest dask.delayed functions within other dask.delayed functions
I am trying to learn dask, and have created the following toy example of a delayed pipeline.
+-----+  +-----+  +-----+
| baz +--+ bar +--+ foo |
+-----+  +-----+  +-----+

So baz has a dependency on bar which in turn has a dependency on foo
I would like all 3 to be delayed tasks, so as each gets executed, they show up as individual tasks in the task pipeline on the dashboard.
My code is as follows:
import dask
import distributed

@dask.delayed
def foo(data:str) -> str:
    return f'foo[{data}]'

@dask.delayed
def bar(data:str) -> str:
    return f'bar[{data}]'

@dask.delayed
def baz(data:str) -> str:
    f = foo(data)
    b = bar(f)
    return f'baz[{b}]'

baz_task = baz('hello world')

client = distributed.Client()
future = client.compute(baz_task)

result = future.result()
print(result)

This doesn't work, as the output of f = foo(data) and b = bar(f) are both Delayed objects.
As such, the result returned from computing baz_task is
baz[Delayed('bar-4c8a0ec0-1d87-43e7-a8af-fee33a9fae3d')]

Obviously my desired output is:
baz[bar[foo[hello world]]]

Things I've tried:
removing the @dask.delayed decorator from foo and bar:
This results in there only being a single task in the task graph, and so one can't follow process on the dashboard.
calling the Delayed object inside the body of baz:
eg:
    f = foo(data)()
                 ^^---- # calling the Delayed object

This returns a delayed apply, whatever that is...
Delayed('apply-145901ce-1271-4387-8f12-4640c9fcd23a')
As far as I can tell, my code follows the decorator example pretty closely in the docs.
What am I doing wrong?

In your example, baz is actually chaining two Delayed call, this is not what you display in your diagram, which a most correct version would be:
+----------------+  
|      baz       |
|+-----+  +-----+|
|+ bar +--+ foo ||
|+-----+  +-----+|
+----------------+

I guess if you want your first diagram, the solution would be:
import dask
import distributed

@dask.delayed
def foo(data:str) -> str:
    return f'foo[{data}]'

@dask.delayed
def bar(data:str) -> str:
    return f'bar[{data}]'

@dask.delayed
def baz(data:str) -> str:
    return f'baz[{b}]'

f = foo('hello world')
b = bar(f)
baz_task = baz(b)

client = distributed.Client()
future = client.compute(baz_task)

result = future.result()
print(result)


Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately result is still baz[Delayed('bar-a3a7cd14-26b2-4d36-8910-bd89990dbfeb')] instead of baz[bar[foo[hello world]]] in this example
